# Wordpress Alter a Theme Admin Page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am really a Drupal developer but got asked to do a bit of Wordpress work and need a little help.

I am running WP3.8.x

We are using a purchased Auction Theme and I wish to extend it's functionality by adding another payment gateway.

Here is what I have:

The Auction theme registers a new admin menu

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'AuctionTheme_admin_main_menu_scr');
```

Then registers the sub page

```
function AuctionTheme_admin_main_menu_scr()
{
  add_submenu_page(
    "AT_menu_",
    __('Payment Gateways','AuctionTheme'),
    AuctionTheme_disp_spcl_cst_pic('gateway_icon.png') . __('Payment Gateways','AuctionTheme'), $capability, 'AT_pay_gate_', 'AuctionTheme_payment_gateways'
  );
  do_action('AuctionTheme_new_page_admin_menu');
}
```

And finally the payment config page is created.

```
function AuctionTheme_payment_gateways()
{
  echo 'The Markup';
  do_action('AuctionTheme_payment_methods_action');
  if(isset($_POST['AuctionTheme_save1'])) {
    update_option('AuctionTheme_paypal_enable',         trim($_POST['AuctionTheme_paypal_enable']));
  }
}
```

Obviously I removed some code as it's not relevant to my question.

So we have our own child theme called mytheme. I thought I could just add a new action?

So in mytheme function file added

```
add_action('AuctionTheme_payment_gateways', 'mytheme_payment_gateways');

function mytheme_payment_gateways () {
  echo 'Test';
}
```

I don't see test in the page …. should? Or how do I go about adding?

Comment: Check [this](http://ottopress.com/2011/actions-and-filters-are-not-the-same-thing/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your `add_action` to work, you must have a [do_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) that calls the same tag.

So, for example, you have:

```
add_action('AuctionTheme_payment_gateways', 'mytheme_payment_gateways');
```

Which means that somewhere in your code (parent or child theme) you must have the following:

```
do_action('AuctionTheme_payment_gateways');
```

So, based on the code you have, I suspect you want to add it here:

```
function AuctionTheme_payment_gateways()
{
  echo 'The Markup';
  do_action('AuctionTheme_payment_methods_action');
  if(isset($_POST['AuctionTheme_save1'])) {
    update_option('AuctionTheme_paypal_enable',         trim($_POST['AuctionTheme_paypal_enable']));
  }
  // Add below do_action
  do_action('AuctionTheme_payment_gateways');
}
```

Of course that's just a guess based on your code - you may need to add the `do_action` somewhere else, but hopefully this explanation gets you pointed in the right direction.